# Laravel Get Data On Conditions

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 tables called **movies** and **movie_dates**.

In **movie_dates** table these are the fields,

```
id | movie_id | year | month
```

**My Question**:  I'm trying to get data from the **movies** table where **year** is `greater` than or `equal` to 1 and **month** is **greater** than or `equal` to 2 in the **movie_dates** table using `movie_id` column.

**What I tried so far,**

```
$months = 2;
$years = 1;

return DB::table('movie_dates')
  ->join('movies', 'movie_dates.movie_id', '=', 'movies.id')
  ->where(['movie_dates.year', '>=', $years], ['movie_dates.month', '>=', $months])
  ->get();
```

**Error I'm getting** : `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column`

Really appreciate it if somebody could help me. Thanks have a nice day.

Comment: You can use [orWhere](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#or-where-clauses) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use array on `where`

```
$months = 2;
$years = 1;

return DB::table('movie_dates')
  ->join('movies', 'movie_dates.movie_id', '=', 'movies.id')
  ->where([['movie_dates.year', '>=', $years], ['movie_dates.month', '>=', $months]])
  ->get();
```

Comment: Now, try this one. I updated my answer.

Comment: This worked I'll accept your answer thanks

Answer (score 1):

use multi `where condition` or use `[] array` for it

```
$months = 2;
$years = 1;

return DB::table('movie_dates')
  ->join('movies', 'movie_dates.movie_id', '=', 'movies.id')
  ->where([['movie_dates.year', '>=', $years], ['movie_dates.month', '>=', $months]])
  ->get();
```

**OR**

```
$months = 2;
$years = 1;

return DB::table('movie_dates')
  ->join('movies', 'movie_dates.movie_id', '=', 'movies.id')
  ->where('movie_dates.year', '>=', $years)
  ->where('movie_dates.month', '>=', $months)
  ->get();
```